# Random WindowsError/IOError with large amount of data

Tags: python, windows

I'm currently experiencing a weird bug with a piece of software created with Python (and some Cython modules). I am running it in Windows 64-bit, but using 32-bit Python.

Part of the program involves downloading a lot of data (up to several gigabytes), and then proceeding to process the data. The software has been relatively stable for a while, but we just introduced a new data source that substantially adds to the quantity of data downloaded. I believe this is when the bug has started occurring.  Running the exact same test case over and over again, I get errors at what seems to be random places.  Here are two of the error messages I've seen so far:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "[filename]"

and

WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: "[filename]"

I will give out more information if it is needed.  Again, I have only seen this error recently with the introduction of a new data source, so I think it has something to do with the volume of data.  Does anybody have an idea what would be causing this?

Thanks!

Edit: for clarification, I was wondering if this may be a problem with Windows/large files, because the fact that it only crashes for this new large data volume seems suspicious to me.

Comment: Please post the traceback message.

Comment: @PaulSeeb - Like I said, these errors are occurring at different places each time, so it seems to be random.  A traceback is not helpful here. It just traces back to sections of my code that call some kind of file operation.

Comment: Sounds like you need some error handling in those places in your code that will deal with locked files and have some retry attempts. I know you may not "want" to believe it, but the first step of debugging is going to the source and diagnosing the problem. you cant just magically determine a solution, especially for such a vague question

Comment: I have already implemented this in the places where I initially saw the error. The problem is that it keeps popping up in different places.  Believe me, I've been doing as much as I can to diagnose the problem. I am just wondering if this is a problem with Windows as there would have to be a different solution in that case.

Comment: Did you recently switch from unix/linux to windows? There are only so many file functions that one uses in a program. You could try overloading those.

Comment: This is designed to be run on Windows. I should note that it has been compiled into an exe using Py2exe. I am going to run a console version of the program to see if this changes anything, but I'm doubtful. I will post back after some more investigation. Mainly I just was hoping that this is a known problem with Windows having troubles with large files.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates it looks like something might be locking the file. With the Process Monitor tool you can monitor if any other process are trying to use the file at the same time.

If this is not the case you need to add a lot more info about your problem, as full error message and the part of the code where it does crash.

[Process Monitor v3.02](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

**Update:**

I think the solution is to open the file in exclusive mode, with a lock..
Check this is out:

[portalocker - Cross-platform (posix/nt) API for flock-style file locking.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65203/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error isn't isolated to a single location in my code.  Running the same test case, sometimes it will crash in one place and other times it won't crash there, but somewhere else. It's bizarre. I have tried using process monitor for the second error but I'm having some trouble. The error doesn't happen with the same file, so I can't just watch a certain file to see what else might be using it. Moreover, each run through takes a few hours so even just trying to replicate the error is a pain.